# File scopes namespaces in C# don't seem to work when building a solution in Azure DevOps

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-devops

As stated, I'm trying to build a dotnet core 6.0 solution in ADO using the `Build Solution` task which is configured like this:

[image: My ADO Build Task]

Several of my source files are using file scope namespaces, like this:

I have a task in my ADO pipeline which is building a solution, when it runs it generates `Error CS1514 { expected`.  This is in reference to a file in my code that looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace MyDefaultNamespace;

public interface MyInterface
{
 ...
```

This builds for me locally in latest visual studio 2022, but it fails in ADO.  What's confusing however is that it's only failing on my feature branch, and not on master (where the file scopes namespaces are also present).  On my feature branch, I've converted the code from dotnet framework to dotnet core.

Comment: "On my feature branch, I've converted the code from dotnet framework to dotnet core." Which version are you targeting, do you specify a language version, and which SDK version is being used?

Comment: Azure DevOps Cloud or Azure DevOps Server? In the latter case, which version? Self-hosted agent? What version of SDKs and Visual Studio are installed there? When inspecting the build logs, what version of msbuild/visual studio is picked up?